# UIVIew set anchor to right edge

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

I have a UIView rectangle that I want to resize the width of programatically. I have that working fine, however when the UIView's width resizes, the left edge stays in place and it is the right edge that moves away/closer. I want the opposite effect of this. I want the right edge to stay fixed and have the UIView resize by moving its left edge. I believe the anchor points are what I should be looking into however i have had no luck

I managed to find `UIView.rightAnchor` however this doesn't seem to do anything. I'm definitely missing something

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using to resize the view and the constraints that you have in place?

Comment: As Paul said, you need to show a screenshot of your IB or your code. Autolayout should make your life easier on this.

Comment: I managed to figure it out myself and it the exact same method as Benjamin Lowry's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unrelated to bounds, there is a very simple way that you can achieve what you are talking about.

This would simply be through animating two changes to the view's frame simultaneously:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, animations: {
        self.view1.frame.size.width -= 100
        self.view1.frame.origin.x += 100
    })
```

This sample code would create something like this:

[image]

Of course you can change the speed of the animation if you want it to be basically instantaneous and such, but this method should work for anything you have in mind.

Comment: A few minutes after posting my question I had a thought and it was exactly this method! Next time I will spend a little longer on my problem before posting it here. Thanks very much nevertheless